# How can this Javascript variable have value?

Tags: javascript

I got this JavaScript code on my webpage:

```
var dLastUpdate = new Date;

var getData = function () {
   alert(dLastUpdate);
   $.post("mypage.aspx?accion=getData", {}, function (data) {RefreshData(data)})
}

function RefreshData(rValue) {    
   dLastUpdate = rValue.UpdateTime;
}
```

getData function it's called many times. In theory, dLastUpdate should be empty the first call, and save the value returned from server. Never the less, in the alert(dLastUpdate); the variable already have value on the first call (page load).

How can this be posible?

Could be that the client is caching the value from previous run?
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the everyday ajax problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Why wouldn't it have a value, it's set to the current date at instantiation ?

Comment: You set it right here: `var dLastUpdate = new Date;`. So of course it has a value. Presumably you meant to just do `var dLastUpdate;` and leave it undefined?

Comment: @elclanrs Actually the problem is entirely independent of the Ajax call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initialise it and give it a value on line 1.

> ```
> var dLastUpdate = new Date;
> ```

That doesn't depend on the Ajax call being processed.

Comment: Haaa I didn't know that! I have the idea that i was creating a variable of date tipe, no givin it a value!

Comment: @ericpap: JS is dynamically typed. Variables don't have a type, only values do.